# Procedurally solve winreg access denied error

Tags: python, error-handling, registry, registrykey, winreg

I want to create a new key with a script, but no matter what I do, I get windows error 5 (access denied)

I know people have solved this error by manually adding permissions inside regedit, but I would like to know if this error is solveable / has a workaround procedurally (in the script itself).

Here is my code:

```
import winreg

REG_PATH = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT"

def set_reg(name, value):
winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH)

registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH, 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)
winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, value)

winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)

set_reg('DisableAbsoluteVolume', 1)
```